# Heart Rate Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, optoelectronics, photodiode

I am building a heart rate circuit followed the instructions in this site:
http://embedded-lab.com/blog/?p=5508

Basically, the circuit works when we place the photo detector and emitter on the fingertip. Here is the waveform.

[image]

However, when I tried on the wrist, most of the time, I get this waveform:

[image]

Could you please giving me suggestions for improvement? Would implementing a feedback loop help? Should we consider using an instrumentation amplifier(instead of an op-amp) to reduce the noise?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real ppg's use two different color LEDs, with one color used to provide a baseline, cleaning up the signal by a good deal.  I recommend *Design of Pulse Oximeters*, 2002, by John Webster.

Comment: We fixed the problem already. It was caused by a bad choice of capacitor. We just slightly adjusted the values. But thank you for your helpful feedbacks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with photoplethysmographs (I'm going to call it a PPG from here on) is they're really, **REALLY** sensitive to motion.

The problem you are having is almost definitely caused by motion in the PPG, relative to the body.

Basically, you can't move whatever appendage the PPG is attached to. As such, a wrist is probably a bad place to put it.

Also, you want the PPG attached somewhere you have lots of perfusion of blood. Areas with high nerve counts (like the fingers) are good for this. Another common place PPGs are attached is the earlobe.
If you need a PPG monitor on someone who is moving, the earlobe is an ideal place. Can you modify your mechanical design to go there?

Comment: Hi Connor, we are targeting a device like this :
http://www.alphaheartrate.com/#product
It's a wrist-based device that could measure heart rate. Is there any direction to overcome the difficulties of wrist-based device?

Comment: I'm not sure how that device works, exactly. They're probably doing a LOT of complicated DSP to recover the heart-rate signal from the sensor readings. FWIW, there are some approaches to recovering a heart-rate reading from noisy data (it has some particular frequency characteristics). However, I'm not really the person to talk to about that. I've done a PPG circuit or two, but I wasn't involved in the software end. You need to look in the medical literature.

Comment: We fixed the problem already. It was caused by a bad choice of capacitor. We just slightly adjusted the values. But thank you for your helpful feedbacks.